# How to write the argument of 'fit' in addLink(): PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I want to add links to other pages to existing PDF by using PyPDF2. My code works when fit argument is '/Fit', however, I want to use the zoom option. After jump to the added link, pages should be displayed as the size maintained. When fit argument is '/XYZ', how should I supply additional arguments?

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter


existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(r"C:\test.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()

pageNum = existing_pdf.getNumPages()


for i in range(pageNum):
    if i == 0:
        packet = io.BytesIO()

        can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
        can.drawString(523, 45, "")
        can.save()

        packet.seek(0)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

        page = existing_pdf.getPage(i)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
        page2 = new_pdf.getPage(0)
        page.mergePage(page2)
        output.addPage(page)
    else:
        packet = io.BytesIO()

        can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
        can.drawString(523, 45, "{}".format(i + 1))
        can.save()

        packet.seek(0)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

        page = existing_pdf.getPage(i)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
        page2 = new_pdf.getPage(0)
        page.mergePage(page2)
        output.addPage(page)
        output.addLink(
            pagenum=i,
            pagedest=0,
            rect=[500, 30, 550, 60],
            border=[0, 0, 0],
            fit="/XYZ",
            0, 0, 1
        )


outputStream = open(r"C:\test_new.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Error messages is below:

```py
output.addLink(pagenum=i,pagedest=0,rect=[500,30,550,60],border = [0,0,0],fit="/XYZ",0,0,1)
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: eyllanesc, thank you for your comment. I tried as you mentioned, however, it didn't work. Error message is bellow, 

output.addLink(0,0,1,pagenum=i,pagedest=0,rect=[500,30,550,60],border = [0,0,0],fit="/XYZ")

TypeError: addLink() got multiple values for argument 'pagenum'

Comment: addLink method should be written as addLink(self, pagenum, pagedest, rect, border=None, fit='/Fit', *args), and when fit argument is '/XYZ', additional arguments is needed. In the original code, this is mentioned as below, :
    Valid zoom arguments (see Table 8.2 of the PDF 1.7 reference for details):
            /XYZ       [left] [top] [zoomFactor]

Comment: so I think I need additional argument for [left], [top] and [zoomFactor], but I can't find out how to write these arguments.

Comment: use `output.addLink(i, 0, [500,30,550,60], [0,0,0],"/XYZ", 0, 0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a Python usage issue, not a PyPDF issue.

You are writing

```py
output.addLink(
    pagenum=i,
    pagedest=0,
    rect=[500, 30, 550, 60],
    border=[0, 0, 0],
    fit="/XYZ",
    0, 0, 1  # <---- here is the issue!
)
```

Hence the pattern `function(foo=bar, 0)`. But Python requires that there are no positional arguments (the zero) after a keyword arguments (foo=bar).

### Solution

Although it's not nice, you can make everything positional:

```py
output.addLink(
    i, 
    0,
    [500, 30, 550, 60],
    [0, 0, 0],
    "/XYZ",
    0, 0, 1
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
pdfWriter.addBookmark("Bookmark 1",1, None, None, False, False, '/FitH',1.3)
```

Please try this snippet, I had this issue too but it is now resolved.